# Returning game object on start position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys,
I am working in Unity (C#) and I have a problem. I have a cube called littleOne that is falling down from start position and another cube that destroys the first cube OnTriggerEnter. When the first cube collides with "destroyer" cube, I want to bring it back to the start position. All game objects are attached correctly to the script. This is my solution:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject littleOne;

    public Vector3 startPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        startPoint = littleOne.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {   
        if(other.gameObject.name == "littleOne") {
            other.gameObject.transform.position = startPoint; //*not working
            //littleOne.transform.position = startPoint; //*not Working
        }
    }
}
```

Lines that has symbol * does nothing, well with these lines I have a problem. I was searching for solution and I tried this way, but nothing happens.

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**: I have solved the problem. This code I have moved to a script with falling operation. It was issue in multiple related script to a object. Thank you for recommendations!

Comment: Maybe just a copy/paste error, but you are missing a ";" at the end of the first not working line

Comment: Also, how can you tell it's not working if you Destroy it right after moving it?

Comment: Voting to close for off-topic because it's just a typo

Comment: It's not problem with ";". Destroy line supposed to be a comment. I edited it.

Comment: There are thousands of similar questions about "Why my collision is not detected" / "Why `OnCollisionEnter`/`OnTriggerEnter` is not called" and so on.... Have you put a simple `Debug.Log(other.name);` inside your `OnTriggerEnter` function to make sure the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Other object and littleOne are referring to the same object which you are destroying:

Dont destroy it:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{   
    if(other.gameObject.name == "littleOne") 
    {
        littleOne.transform.position = startPoint; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to defend _"not working"_ by some evidence my friend. Whats the behaviour of the object?

Comment: It just passes through.

Comment: Is it going back to start position? are you stopping it from falling by disabling gravity or something? is littleOne actually named as littleOne?